# Is '.herokuapp' extension in personal domain sign of unprofessional approach ?

Tags: domains, heroku

As title implies, do extensions like `.herokuapp` or `github.io` in portfolio domain show lack of professionalism ?

Or is it completely irrelevant ?

I've pushed my portfolio to heroku, and I wonder is it okey if I leave it there, e.g `www.myname.herokuapp.com.`

Comment: Since this is a "personal" portfolio I would say it doesn't matter. But this may be down to personal opinion, depending on the type of portfolio.

Comment: It looks cool if you use domain same as your surname for portfolio/cv , and some sort of professionalism.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good reasons not to leave your website on a subdomain of hosting company:

- You won't have control over that domain name once you leave that hosting company.
- The hosting company could take the subdomain away from you at any time for pretty much any reason.
- The hosting company could go out of business, taking your entire site down, and making the name forever unreachable.
- Search engines often take a dim view of free subdomains because they find so much spam on them.

A professional would get their own domain name.

- You can move from one host to another and keep your own domain name easily.  This allows your to choose hosting based on price and performance rather than being tied to the one host that will allow you to keep your sites name.
- A registered domain name is fairly difficult to take away from you compared to a free subdomain.  There usually needs to be some sort of trademark infringement to lose a registered second level domain.
- You won't be subject to search engine penalties levied against other sites that share the top level domain of your web host.  Many spammers don't want to pay the minimal yearly fees for a domain name.  Especially since spam content on that domain name would get it penalized in short order.   Therefore search engines view paying the yearly fees for a domain name as a minimal sign of quality.

So yes, using a free subdomain from your hosting company is unprofessional.